# Implementing Stochastic Gradient Descent Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent, stochastic

I've been trying to implement stochastic gradient descent as part of a recommendation system following these equations:

[image]

I have:

```
for step in range(max_iter):
        e = 0
        for x in range(len(R)):
            for i in range(len(R[x])):
                if R[x][i] > 0:
                    exi = 2 * (R[x][i] - np.dot(Q[:,i], P[x,:]))
                    qi, px = Q[:,i], P[x,:]

                    qi += _mu_2 * (exi * px - (2 * _lambda_1 * qi))
                    px += _mu_1 * (exi * qi - (2 * _lambda_2 * px))

                    Q[:,i], P[x,:] = qi, px
```

The output I expect isn't quite right but I can't really put a finger on it.
Please help me to identify the problem I have in my code.

Much appreciate your support

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am looking for a solution too.

Comment: unfortunately I never did. but I reckon I should ask my fellow classmates who scored 100 on this one for their solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update *qi* and *px*, you should exchange *mu1* and *mu2*.

Comment: Took me 4 years to realise mu1 and mu2 are supposed to be swapped around. just like you suggested :)